# Why do I get "permission danied" message when I commit in visual-studio-2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssis

The full message is

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open("ssis/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos.dbmdl"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path ssis/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos.dbmdl
```

Perform the commit command in visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should

1. Correctly configure the .gitignore file. Use content from
   https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore.
   This is specific content for VIsual-studio
2. eliminate the file that is being presented in the message of the stage area with the command presented at the end. Run this pass as many times as necessary

> ```
> git rm ssis/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos/DatawarehouseSucos.dbmdl --cached
> ```